# Data-bind for tootltip not working in asp.net _knockout web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

In my asp.net web application i'm trying to add a tooltip using the knockout data-bind attribute

below is the code for the tooltip

```
<li class="" >
     <a  href="#MyActivity"  data-bind="tooltip: { title: 'Assign points for activities', trigger: 'hover', placement: 'top' }" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">
        <span>My Activity</span>
     </a>
 </li>
```

I have used tooltip is similar fashion in lot of places throughout the application and all of them are working also..

I also tried adding it to the li and span still nothing happens

Don't know why this is not working..

Please guide

Thanks

Comment: Try to specified the `attr:` insted of `tooltip:` this will work.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Also, make sure the `js` file which contains `ko.bindingHandlers.tooltip` code is referred in the page.